# Two Timestamp Formats in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, posix

Im have a time stamp column that I am converting into a POSIXct.  The problem is that there are two different formats in the same column, so if I use the more common conversion the other gets converted into NA.

```
MC$Date    
12/1/15 22:00    
12/1/15 23:00    
12/2/15    
12/2/15 1:00    
12/2/15 2:00
```

I use the following code to convert to a POSIXct:

```
MC$Date <- as.POSIXct(MC$Date, tz='MST', format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

The results:

```
MC$Date    
15-12-01 22:00:00    
15-12-01 23:00:00    
NA    
15-12-02 01:00:00    
15-12-02 02:00:00
```

I have tried using a logic vector to identify the issue then correct it but can't find an easy solution.

Answer (score 4):

The `lubridate` package was designed to deal with situations like this.

```
dt <- c(
"12/1/15 22:00",
"12/1/15 23:00", 
"12/2/15",
"12/2/15 1:00",
"12/2/15 2:00"
)
dt
[1] "12/1/15 22:00" "12/1/15 23:00" "12/2/15"       "12/2/15 1:00"  "12/2/15 2:00" 
lubridate::mdy_hm(dt, truncated = 2)
[1] "2015-12-01 22:00:00 UTC" "2015-12-01 23:00:00 UTC" "2015-12-02 00:00:00 UTC"
[4] "2015-12-02 01:00:00 UTC" "2015-12-02 02:00:00 UTC"
```

The `truncated` parameter  indicates how many formats can be missing.

You may add the `tz` parameter to specify which time zone to parse the date with if `UTC` is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic vector approach could work. Maybe in tandem with an temporary vector for holding the parsed dates without clobbering the unparsed ones. Something like this:

```
dates <- as.POSIXct(MC$Date, tz='MST', format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
dates[is.na(dates)] <- as.POSIXct(MC[is.na(dates),], tz='MST', format = '%m/%d/%Y')
MC$Date <- dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your datetimes are separated with a space between date and time, you could use strsplit to extract only the date part.

```
extractDate <- function(x){ strsplit(x, split = " " )[[1]][1] }
MC$Date <- sapply( MC$Date, extractDate )
```

Then go ahead and convert any way you like, without worrying about the time part getting in the way.